# jquery ajax callback difficulty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
                // type: "POST",
                url: webMethod,
                data: $.toJSON(params),
                // dataType: "json",
                // contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (obj) {

                    if (obj == 1) {
                        window.location = 'Postpaid/Dashboard';
                        // $.mobile.changePage('#dashboard', 'slide', false, true);
                    }
                    else if (obj == 0) {
                        window.location = 'Prepaid/Dashboard';
                    }
                    else if (obj == -1) {
                        window.location = 'Home/Index/#login1';
                    }
                    else {
                        $.mobile.changePage('#login2', 'slide', false, true);

                        $('#txtMSISDN2').val(obj.Pin.MSISDN);
                        $('#txtPin').val(obj.Pin.PIN);
                        $('#txtMSISDN2').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error returned.');
                }
            });
```

From the method I return a flag integer. I want to redirect the user to the appropriate webpage according to the return int. However, this code doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Do i use window.location incorrectly here? Thank you very much!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you verified that `obj` is really an integer and not something like {'x': 1} ?

Comment: what does `obj` contain? Is it getting in the succes scope, or does it fail? What exactly is not working

Comment: the method returns an integer that's for sure. I check that while debugging with Firebug in the response. The if statements do note execute. None of them..

Comment: I guess it should be window.location.href = ....

Comment: if you put `alert(obj);` as the first line in `success` what does it alert ?

Comment: Gaby, funny thing the alert doesn't execute... The response from the server method is -1 so that means else if (obj == -1) {
                        window.location = 'Home/Index/#login1';
                    }
should execute..

Comment: if the `alert` doesn't execute, then the `success` method is not being called.. What is the status of the ajax call (*it should be 200 or 304*)?

Comment: How do you know the response from server is -1 if your success callback doesn't fire?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Agree with Gaby, if the alert doesn't execute then you're not getting a successful ajax response. Inspect the request and the response from the ajax call using Firebug's Network tab to view the response or you can also use something like Fiddler.

Comment: use window.location.href as Sedat suggested http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Answer (score 1):

My feedback...

1. the data could be directly your params, no need to use $.toJSON
2. add a console.debug(obj) to see what's really returned by JQM (and not just Fiddler)
3. replace those window.location with $.mobile.changePage, that's why it's there (and will take care of other stuff for you as well)

Once you tells us what #2 returns, we'll be able to provide better solutions to your problem.